Which keyword to use for extracting data from netCDF file
The header of a netCDF file reads:
netcdf gpw_v4_population_density_rev11_2pt5_min {
dimensions:
        longitude = 8640 ;
        latitude = 4320 ;
        raster = UNLIMITED ; // (20 currently)
variables:
        double longitude(longitude) ;
                longitude:units = "degrees_east" ;
                longitude:long_name = "longitude" ;
        double latitude(latitude) ;
                latitude:units = "degrees_north" ;
                latitude:long_name = "latitude" ;
        int raster(raster) ;
                raster:units = "unknown" ;
                raster:long_name = "raster" ;
        float Population\ Density\,\ v4.11\ \(2000\,\ 2005\,\ 2010\,\ 2015\,\ 2020\)\:\ 2.5\ arc-minutes(raster, latitude, longitude) ;
                Population\ Density\,\ v4.11\ \(2000\,\ 2005\,\ 2010\,\ 2015\,\ 2020\)\:\ 2.5\ arc-minutes:units = "Persons per square kilometer" ;
                Population\ Density\,\ v4.11\ \(2000\,\ 2005\,\ 2010\,\ 2015\,\ 2020\)\:\ 2.5\ arc-minutes:_FillValue = -3.4e+38f ;
                Population\ Density\,\ v4.11\ \(2000\,\ 2005\,\ 2010\,\ 2015\,\ 2020\)\:\ 2.5\ arc-minutes:missing_value = -3.4e+38f ;
                Population\ Density\,\ v4.11\ \(2000\,\ 2005\,\ 2010\,\ 2015\,\ 2020\)\:\ 2.5\ arc-minutes:long_name = "Population Density, v4.11 (2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020): 2.5 arc-minutes" ;
                Population\ Density\,\ v4.11\ \(2000\,\ 2005\,\ 2010\,\ 2015\,\ 2020\)\:\ 2.5\ arc-minutes:min = 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., -9999., -9999., 0., 0., 0., 0. ;
                Population\ Density\,\ v4.11\ \(2000\,\ 2005\,\ 2010\,\ 2015\,\ 2020\)\:\ 2.5\ arc-minutes:max = 52542.421875, 53915.54296875, 59666.02734375, 78523.484375, 103340.84375, 207., 767642., 3., 21.5139427185059, 21.5139389038086, 32767., 6., 2015., 6., 6., 6., 2011., 2015., 4., 2016. ;

// global attributes:
                :proj4 = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" ;
                :Conventions = "CF-1.4" ;
                :created_by = "R, packages ncdf4 and raster (version 2.8-4)" ;
                :date = "2018-11-16 10:27:52" ;

I try reading it as usual with:
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

sample_file = "/home/ubuntu/POP/gpw_v4_population_density_rev11_2pt5_min.nc"
sample_dataset = nc.Dataset(sample_file)
T_latitudes = sample_dataset.variables["latitude"][:]   
T_longitudes = sample_dataset.variables["longitude"][:] 
popu1 = sample_dataset.variables["Population"][:]

This works for latitudes and longitudes (as expected) but I'm unsure which is the right syntax to extract the different populations. I have tried several syntaxes without success with the above one generating the error:
KeyError: 'Population'


Have you tried Population Density or Population Density, v4.11?

Yes, they don't work either with the same error.

Or Population Density, v4.11 (2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020)

Have you tried to e.g. print(sample_dataset.variables) to see if it'd print out the names?

It's returning float32 Population Density, v4.11 (2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020): 2.5 arc-minutes(raster, latitude, longitude). Let me try some combinations because I'm unsure how to handle the double parentheses.

Have tried popu1 = sample_dataset.variables["Population Density, v4.11 (2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020): 2.5 arc-minutes(raster, latitude, longitude)"], popu1 = sample_dataset.variables["Population Density, v4.11 (): 2.5 arc-minutes()"][:][:,:,:], popu1 = sample_dataset.variables["Population Density, v4.11: 2.5 arc-minutes"][:][:,:,:] but the error persists. I'm missing something here.

If variables[x] fails already, adding more stuff to the end like variables[x][:] and variables[x][:][:,:,:] is pointless.

Have you tried popu1 = sample_dataset.variables["Population Density, v4.11 (2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020): 2.5 arc-minutes"]?

Hi @mkrieger. Sorry as, after the early morning, I've had several commitments. Your suggestion seems to have done the trick.

As @mkrieger1 commented under the OP, the variable name is the rather cumbersome "Population Density, v4.11 (2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020): 2.5 arc-minutes". The slashes in the header text are escaping non-syntactical characters in the name (spaces, commas, brackets, semi-colon). On top of that, the file has all manner of idiosyncrasies that make interpretation cumbersome, two obvious ones being:

The contents of the raster dimension are unclear from the file. When opening the file as a raster in R (the original processing format of the data), the layers are simply called "Population Density, v4.11 (2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020): 2.5 arc-minutes_raster=1" (note the "=1" at the end) to "*=20". You need an accompanying file to understand what the layers mean. Fine, but then don't say that you adhere to the "CF-1.4" conventions because these require the file to be self-descriptive.
The CRS is stored as a global attribute "proj4". While that is superfluous (it is the default CRS), if it is included it should be a grid mapping variable.

